# Future LTS upgrade from 22.10

Tags: upgrade

I already upgraded to 22.10 What do I need to do to pickup the next LTS track?
I was on 22.04 LTS

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 is the first release in the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS *development* cycle.  There are three non-LTS releases released in the two year full development cycle; ie. 22.10, 23.04, 23.10 before the final 24.04 LTS is released. You're already on the 24.04 release cycle, but need to *release-upgrade* through each release as only users of the last LTS cycle can *release-upgrade* directly to 24.04 (after 24.04.1 LTS has been released)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The next LTS will be 24.04, to be released on April 2024.

You can upgrade from 22.10->23.04->23.10->24.04 (each of the interim releases will be supported for nine months).

If you don't want to upgrade so many times and want to keep using the same operating system, then reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 (it will be supported until 2027, and you can directly upgrade 22.04 -> 24.04 when it will be released).

Comment: Thanks, so I need to do a 9 month update until I get back on 24.04 LTS. What if I go 12 months, can I still upgrade? Say I do a  22.10->23.04-->24.04 LTS. What happens?

Comment: There will be no upgrade path from 23.04 to 24.04.

Comment: However, you can always fresh install any version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @daniel451 24.04 will be released in April 2024. If you want to use LTS, use 22.04. Otherwise, use 23.04.